# AutoComplete TextView from a Local Database File, Android Studio, Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, syntax

Please help me, I'm trying to prepopulate my autocomplete text view with a local database file, I keep getting this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.saud.app.autocompletesample/com.saud.app.autocompletesample.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "drugstable": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: drugstable
```

Below my code

`DatabaseHelper.java`

```java
package com.saud.app.autocompletesample;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.material.shape.CutCornerTreatment;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrugsDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private final Context myContext;


    private static final String database_name = "aaa.db";
    private static final int version = 1;
    public static final String table_name = "drugstable";
    public static final String column_id = "id";
    public static final String column_name = "drug";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DrugsDataBase(Context context) {

        super(context, database_name, null, version);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(database_name)
                .toString();
    }

    public void createDataBase()
            throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            // By calling this method and
            // the empty database will be
            // created into the default system
            // path of your application
            // so we are gonna be able
            // to overwrite that database
            // with our database.
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error(
                        "Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if the database already exist
    // to avoid re-copying the file each
    // time you open the application
    // return true if it exists
    // false if it doesn't.
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            checkDB
                    = SQLiteDatabase
                    .openDatabase(
                            myPath, null,
                            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database doesn't exist yet.
            Log.e("message", "" + e);
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your
     * local assets-folder to the just
     * created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it
     * can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transferring bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase()
            throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput
                = myContext.getAssets()
                .open(database_name);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput
                = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the
        // inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase()
            throws SQLException {
        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        db = SQLiteDatabase
                .openDatabase(
                        myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        // close the database.
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase,

        int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {
            // It is an abstract method which is
            // used to perform different task
            // based on the version of database.
        }



    public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(table_name, null);
        cursor.moveToNext();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            names.add(cursor.getString(1));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return names;
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```java
package com.saud.app.autocompletesample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private DrugsDataBase dataBase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        dataBase = new DrugsDataBase(this);
        names = dataBase.getNames();

        ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, names);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the getNames method of your DrugsDataBase class, you should construct a proper SQL query using the query method. The query should retrieve specific columns from the drugstable table. Here's how the query should look like:

```
public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Define the columns you want to retrieve
    String[] columns = { column_name }; // Only retrieve the "drug" column
    
    // Query the table to retrieve the names
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(column_name)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        
        cursor.close();
    }
    
    return names;
}
```

This query retrieves the values from the "drug" column of the drugstable table using the query method. The resulting Cursor will contain only the "drug" column values, and you iterate through the Cursor to populate the ArrayList with the drug names.

Ensure you've declared the column_name constant correctly and that it matches the actual column name in your database table definition.